# ¿Cómo hago para que al pulsar en el botón pase a la siguiente pregunta? Python y Django

Tags: python, django, bootstrap

Buenas, estoy terminando una practica que tengo que hacer para el grado superior y consiste en montar una pequeña aplicacion que genere encuestas, yo la he enfocado a una pizzeria, entonces las preguntas son: Pizza, complementos, bebida y postres.
Una vez que me meto en pizza, que es la primera, la elijo y se añade una unidad a los votos, pero lo que quiero es que al pulsar, se añada una unidad y ademas pase a la siguiente pregunta... 
Este es el codigo de la pregunta:

```html
{% load staticfiles %}
<html lang="es">
<head>
  <title>Pizzeria Romero</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'ProyectoF/css/style.css' %}" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <h1 align="center">Pizzería Romero</h1>      
    <p align="center">Bienvenido a la Pizzería Romero, aquí podras hacer tus pedidos online.</p>
     <p align="center">Aún no contamos con servicio a domicilio, por lo que tendrá que recoger su pedido en el local.</p>
  </div>
<div align="center">
<h1>{{ pregunta.pregunta }}</h1>

{% if error_message %}<p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>{% endif %}

<form action="{% url 'ProyectoF:votos' pregunta.id %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{% for respuesta in pregunta.respuesta_set.all %}
    <input type="radio" name="respuesta" id="respuesta{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ respuesta.id }}" />
    <label for="respuesta{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ respuesta.respuesta }}</label><br />
{% endfor %}
<input type="submit" value="Siguiente" />
</form>
</div>
```

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: hola Juanky, disculpa por el off-topic, me podrías decir donde estas cursando el cicle que imparten django? gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Aquí te dejo una idea rápida para que le puedas dar solución a tu problema:

Usa una `View` para mostrar la pregunta con sus posibles respuestas. Esto ya lo debes tener, pero además, que pase el `id` de la próxima pregunta a mostrar en una variable, para que cuando hagas click en tu plantilla en <kbd>*Siguiente*</kbd> la envie y sepa que pregunta mostrar a continuación.

Eso lo puedes manejar en la vista simplemente preguntando si es `POST`:

- Si es `GET` comienzas la encuesta desde 0.
- Si te llega por `POST` procesas la respuesta que te enviaron y rendereas el template de la nueva pregunta. Cuando no queden más, rendireccionas para donde quieras.

**Ejemplo de solución rápida**

Supongamos que tienes unos `modelos` similares a estos:

```
class Encuesta(models.Model):
    titulo = models.CharField(max_length=255)


class Pregunta(models.Model):
    pregunta = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    encuesta = models.ForeignKey(Encuesta)


class Respuesta(models.Model):
    respuesta = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Pregunta')
    pregunta = models.ForeignKey(Pregunta)
```

Alguna `vista` similar a esta:

```
def encuesta_view(request, encuesta_id):
    # obtienes la encuesta
    encuesta = get_object_or_404(Encuesta, encuesta_id)

    # obtienes las preguntas asociadas a esa encuesta
    # en el orden en que las quieras mostrar
    # por ejemplo las voy a ordenar por id
    preguntas = encuesta.pregunta_set.all().order_by(id)

    # acuerdate siempre de verificar si existe alguna pregunta asociada a la encuesta
    # que quieras mostrar, para evitar errores
    pregunta = preguntas.first()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        # aqui puedes hacer tus validaciones
        # luego añades tu voto

        # aqui obtengo el id de la pregunta q se mostro anteriormente
        # suponiendo q los estas enviando desde el template, lo cual puedes hacer con un input type='hidden'
        pregunta_actual = request.POST['pregunta_id']
        preguntas = preguntas.filter(encuesta_id__gt=int(pregunta_actual))

        # verifico q queden mas preguntas
        # si quedan obtengo la proxima y vuelvo a la vista de la siguiente
        # si no quedan, regresa al listado de encuestas o a donde tu desees
        if preguntas.count > 0:
            pregunta = preguntas.first()
        else:
            return render(request, 'encuesta/encuestas.html', {})


    return render(request, 'encuesta/pregunta.html', {'pregunta': pregunta})
```

de seguro existen mejores maneras de hacer esto, pero esto te debe resolver

saludos

Comment: Eso es básicamente lo que quiero hacer, pero tengo ya la cabeza un poco quemada y no se exactamente como plantarlo en el codigo.Y  el codigo de la pregunta  es el codigo de la view en la que se muestra la pregunta con sus posibles respuestas.